# Tables listing values, not frequencies in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two data vectors, one that returns one of four categories of people (strings) and one that returns a continuous score for each person ranging from 0 to 1. I would like to make a data table OR matrix using the four categories as columns and the corresponding scores listed in their respective columns. I tried making a table with these two data vectors, but that only gave me a table of the frequencies of each score within the categories. Is there a way to list all the scores individually? The reason I want to do this is to calculate a mean score for each category, and right now R only returns the mean frequency for a score in each category. Hope that makes sense!

```
           0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9  1
  CAT A    0   2  12  16  30  44  47  41  46  28 88
  CAT B    0   1   0   2   3   4   9   6  10   4  8
  CAT C    0   2   3   4   4   5  13   6   7   4 10
  CAT D    0   0   0   1   0   3   4   2   2   0  3
```

what I have now ^

```
CAT A   CAT B   CAT C   CAT D
.1        .2     .4      .6
.5        .9     .3      .8
.7        .1      1      .8
.8        .5      .2     .3
.
.
.
.
```

what I would like to have ^

Answer (score 1):

To calculate a mean score for each category you can simply use the aggregate function:

```
urdata <- data.frame(strings = sample(LETTERS[1:4], n, replace = T), 
                     continuous = runif(n, 0, 1))
urdata
#   strings continuous
#1        C  0.1213604
#2        D  0.8630392
#3        D  0.3409612
#4        A  0.3243816
#5        D  0.5842743
#6        A  0.2332454
#7        C  0.7025285
#8        B  0.6720415
#9        A  0.7720547
#10       C  0.5592304

aggregate(continuous ~ strings, urdata, mean)
#  strings continuous
#1       A  0.4432273
#2       B  0.6720415
#3       C  0.4610398
#4       D  0.5960916
```

Comment: I suspect you're right in suggesting not to bother making the requested matrix, and just jumping straight to the answer.